# How could it be possible for `-applicationDidBecomeActive` to be dispatched on two separate background threads simultaneously?

Tags: multithreading, macos, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter

We're having a weird crash-- now I'm now sure what's causing it, but one weird thing I've noticed is that all the crash logs have `-applicationDidBecomeActive` on two separate background threads

```
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00007fffaebac456 semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   MyApp                               0x0000000107389da1 -[OutputManager(TechSmithCloud) reloadCloudDestinations] (OutputManager+TechSmithCloud.m:59)
2   MyApp                               0x000000010728c4b4 __44-[AppController applicationDidBecomeActive:]_block_invoke (AppController.m:696)
3   libdispatch.dylib                    0x00007fffaea57f5f _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
4   libdispatch.dylib                    0x00007fffaea4f128 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
5   libdispatch.dylib                    0x00007fffaea51099 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 917
6   libdispatch.dylib                    0x00007fffaea50cb7 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 99
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00007fffaec9b746 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00007fffaec9b221 start_wqthread + 13


Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00007fffaebac456 semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   MyApp                               0x0000000107389da1 -[OutputManager(TechSmithCloud) reloadCloudDestinations] (OutputManager+TechSmithCloud.m:59)
2   MyApp                               0x000000010728c4b4 __44-[AppController applicationDidBecomeActive:]_block_invoke (AppController.m:696)
3   libdispatch.dylib                    0x00007fffaea57f5f _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
4   libdispatch.dylib                    0x00007fffaea4f128 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
5   libdispatch.dylib                    0x00007fffaea51099 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 917
6   libdispatch.dylib                    0x00007fffaea50cb7 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 99
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00007fffaec9b746 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00007fffaec9b221 start_wqthread + 13
```

And I can't repro it (I log out a statement in `-applicationDidBecomeActive` and it only ever logs out once at a time)

so I'm not sure how it's possible, or if it's an actual issue

Maybe it's a semaphore-related thing?

Here's the code:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^
                  {
                     [[OutputManager sharedOutputManager] reloadCloudDestinations];
                  });

}
```

EDIT:
Code for `-reloadCloudDestinations`

```
-(void) reloadCloudDestinations
{
   [self setupCloudLibrary];
   TSCAccount* account = [TSCCloudServices activeAccount];
   if( account.status == TSCAccount_SignedIn )
   {
      dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
      __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

      @try
      {
         AFHTTPSessionManager *test = (AFHTTPSessionManager*)[(TSCAccountHTTPSession*)[self.libraryCore valueForKey:@"sessionManager"] valueForKey:@"httpClient"];
         NSLog(@"%@", test);
         [self.libraryCore destinationsWithActions:NEVER_TRANSLATE(@"publish,list") completionBlock:^(NSArray *destinations, NSError *error) {

            @try
            {
               if( error == nil )
               {
                  [weakSelf createButtonsForNewDestinationsNotAlreadyPresent:destinations];
               }
               else
               {
                  NSLog(@"destinationsWithBlock error: %@", error);
               }
            }
            @catch (NSException* exception)
            {
               NSLog(@"reloadCloudDestinations - destinationWithBlock completion - An exception was thrown %@", exception);
            }
            @finally
            {
              dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
            }
         }];

         dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
      }
      @catch (NSException* exception)
      {
         NSLog(@"reloadCloudDestinations - An exception was thrown %@", exception);
         dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backtraces have the symbol `__44-[AppController applicationDidBecomeActive:]_block_invoke`. That's not the `-applicationDidBecomeActive:` method itself. It the name for the function that the compiler generated for the block that appears in your `-applicationDidBecomeActive:` method.

The block function appears on background threads because you're dispatching it to a queue other than the main queue. That's not a problem, just an explanation.

It appears multiple times presumably because your app became active, resigned active, and then became active again over its life. Each time it became active, `-applicationDidBecomeActive:` would have been invoked on the main thread. That would have submitted the block to a global concurrent queue and, assuming that there's an available CPU core and other system resources, it would then execute on the background thread.

An open question is why the blocks are still running when your crash happens rather than having completed in short order. You don't show the code for `-[OutputManager reloadCloudDestinations]`, so it's hard to know. Evidently, it waits on a semaphore whose count happens to be zero or less.

Comment: Ah that makes sense.  I edited my post to include the code.  But it looks like we dispatch the network request, which uses a semaphore to block the return until the network requests finishes

So if the network request takes long enough, and the app becomes active twice within that time, there would be issues?

Comment: No issues inherent to that situation. That's simply a reason why those threads are still there. Whether or not your code copes with two requests potentially in progress at the same time, and potentially finishing up simultaneously, is beyond the scope of what I can tell here. Do you really suspect that the network requests are so slow that you can switch away and back before one completes? It seems more likely that you have a code path in `-destinationsWithActions:completionBlock:` where the completion block is never called.